# Circleci: How to deploy depending on git tag

Tags: git, circleci, git-tag

Is there a way to restrict circleci deployment on checkings that have a specific git tag?

Currently I am using this

```
...
deployment:
  dockerhub:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - docker login -e $DOCKER_EMAIL -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASS
      - docker push abcdef
```

Instead of `branch: master` I would like to write something like `tag: /release_.*/`

Background: I would like to set docker tags depending on git tags. So for example, whenever something is committed to master, a new docker images with `latest` tag will be created and pushed. Whenever a special git tag is set (e.g. `release_1.0_2015-06-13`) a new docker image with a tag `1.0` will be created and pushed.

Alternative is to only use different branches according to the different tags. But I would like to use tags to mark a specific release.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[It looks like this was added](https://circleci.com/docs/configuration#tags) since Kim answered.

> Normally, pushing a tag will not run a build. If there is a deployment configuration with a `tag` property that matches the name of the tag you created, we will run the build and the deployment section that matches.
>
> In the below example, pushing a tag named `release-v1.05` would trigger a build & deployment. Pushing a tag `qa-9502` would not trigger a build.
>
> ```
> deployment:
>   release:
>     tag: /release-.*/
>     owner: circleci
>     commands:
>       - ./deploy_master.sh
> ```

Comment: Is there a way to get the tag name in the build? Theres an environment var for CIRCLE_BRANCH but I didnt see one for CIRCLE_TAG

Comment: There is CIRCLE_TAG instead of CIRCLE_BRANCH if the build is triggered by pushing a new tag.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work in the 'deployment' section. I have an `s3_location` section with `key_pattern: builds/{TAG}-{BUILD_NUM}.zip` and `key_pattern: builds/{CIRCLE_TAG}-{BUILD_NUM}.zip`. Neither of which fill in the {tag}

Comment: The `tag: /regexp/` feauture doesnt work for one reason: the git checkout step on circle doesn't gets the tags ... I think its a bug. But its easy to workaround: Add `git fetch --tags` as a **pre** step.

Comment: lalyos, which pre step you mean?

Comment: @lalyos There is no "pre" step in `checkout`. Only `post` and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

This is Kim from CircleCI.

To archive what you want to do, I think you must be able to trigger a build when a new tag is pushed to Github. However, only a new commit will trigger a build, so it seems this is not doable as of now. Sorry!

UPDATE: This feature has now been implemented: https://circleci.com/docs/configuration/#tags

Comment: Is this a regression? tag based builds was clearly supported in the recent past and users have shared theirs of using it experiences.

Comment: The feature was added after Kim made this answer. @Dean's answer links to the correct resource.

Answer (score 3):

I'm putting this here for people that followed the [documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/configuration/#tags) but didn't get this to work. CircleCI seems to ignore tags at all if you have a `branch` `only` configuration in your general settings. Tagged commits will appear as "Not run" that way.

To build only on specific branches and deploy on a specific tag, use the `branch` and `ignore` option along with a negative lookahead regex:

```
# circle.yml
general:
  branches:
    ignore:
      - /^(?!master).*$/
deployment:
  beta:
    tag: /v[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*(-.*)*/
    owner: mediafreakch
    commands:
      - deploy.sh
```

This will build every commit to `master` and deploy if it's a tagged commit. To tag a commit, I use `npm version`.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you're currently in bitbucket beta, it doesn't look like tags work under any circumstance.  I've tried this same approach here but in bitbucket, and Circle doesn't do any of the deploy commands.

Comment: @Jack How do you name your tags? Do you do annotated tags using the `git tag -a` flag (that's what `npm version` does)?

Comment: No, using non-annotated flags.  Does that factor into if $CIRCLE_TAG is present or not?  I'll give an annotated tag a try and see if that makes a difference, then report back here.  Good call @mediafreakch

Comment: Nope, still didn't work.  Seems that `$CIRCLE_TAG` isn't present.  I bet it's a bit bucket (in beta) bug.  I'm working around this now by just running a script with determines if there's a tag matching a regex, then either skipping everything (`exit 0`), or continue forward with deployment.  Thanks mediafreakch for the thought, but tags just aren't there (annotated or not).

Comment: annotated tags does not make a difference for github either

Comment: @tom The configuration as above works for my github repository. Make sure that you see the tags you created using `git tag` and that your `tag` regex matches those names. You have to change the `owner` to your github user as well of course!

Comment: @mediafreakch thanks, but something is still missing something in the  solution.  checkout.post has `git fetch --tags && git tag` (i.e. 'test-8') as well as `echo $CIRCLE_TAG` which is always unset. For deployment.release I have `tag: /test-.*/` and `owner: $CIRCLE_PROJECT_USERNAME` ( I have also tried my user without the env var).

Comment: @Tom What about if you tag a commit locally and then push it `git push && git push --tags` ? Also, do you have `general.branches.only` set?

Comment: @mediafreakch - i thought pushing the tags and then commit was the only way i could do it - is there another? No branch restrictions, here's my [circle.yml](https://github.com/byu-oit-appdev/wabs/blob/issue-13-official-docker-image/circle.yml).

Comment: For those who had problems before, I updated the tag regex to include pre-releases as well. CircleCi requires a full-match for the tag you specify, otherwise it won't deploy anything

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full working example note version needs to be 2.1 or above. The staging_workflow will run only on push to main branch (not on a git tags push) and the prod_workflow will run only on a git tag push (not a push to main) which starts with 'R..' - intended use is for production deploys to git tag your commit with a release tag:

`git tag -a R2.1.0 -m "Some new release feature"`

Then push the tag:

`git push origin --tags`

Also included is as example of how to integrate with AWS using assume-role-with-web-identity (this is preferred over using permanent AWS credentials stored on CirceCI) It assumes you have set up an IDP in AWS (you just need the CircleCI organisation Id and add an admin role) then store the role ARN in CircleCI Organisations context. The example here is if you have 2 AWS accounts for staging and prod, contexts are aws-staging and aws-prod respectively, then the only env var you need in the context is: AWS_ROLE_ARN although you may wish to include AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.

Here's an excerpt from my package.json (nodeJs project) so you can see the scripts the pipeline is running including linting, testing and CICDPackage & CICDDeploy (AWS SAM/ serverless project - for staging and prod using ‘sam package’ and ‘sam deploy’, I use `sam sync` for dev stacks as it's faster):

package.json excerpt:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "watchTestFiles": "jest --watch --verbose=false",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.js\"",
    "build": "node scripts/bundle",
    "CICDPackage": "sam package --s3-bucket serverless-packaged-artifacts --template template.yaml --output-template-file templateOut.yaml --region eu-west-1",
    "CICDDeploy": "sam deploy --template-file templateOut.yaml --stack-name some-stack-name --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM --region eu-west-1"
}
```

config.yml

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  aws-cli: circleci/aws-cli@3.1.1

jobs:
  test_and_lint:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:lts
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: npm i
      - run: npm run lint
      - run: npm run test

  deploy_staging:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:lts
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: npm i
      - run: npm run build
      - aws-cli/setup
      # if using standard AWS user credentials stored as organisation context & not OIDC token
      # - run: aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --profile default
      # - run: aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --profile default
      # - run: aws configure set default.region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
      - run: curl -L https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/releases/latest/download/aws-sam-cli-linux-x86_64.zip -o aws-sam-cli-linux-x86_64.zip
      - run: unzip aws-sam-cli-linux-x86_64.zip -d sam-installation
      - run: sudo ./sam-installation/install
      - run:
          name: AWS authentication
          command: |
            read -r AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY AWS_SESSION_TOKEN \<<< \
              $(aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity \
              --role-arn ${AWS_ROLE_ARN} \
              --role-session-name "CircleCI-${CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_ID}-${CIRCLE_JOB}" \
              --web-identity-token $CIRCLE_OIDC_TOKEN \
              --duration-seconds 3600 \
              --query 'Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]' \
              --output text)
              echo export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" >> $BASH_ENV
              echo export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" >> $BASH_ENV
              echo export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="$AWS_SESSION_TOKEN" >> $BASH_ENV
      - run: npm run CICDPackage
      - run: npm run CICDDeploy

  deploy_prod:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:lts
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: npm i
      - run: npm run build
      - aws-cli/setup
      # if using standard AWS user credentials stored as organisation context & not OIDC token
      # - run: aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --profile default
      # - run: aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --profile default
      # - run: aws configure set default.region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
      - run: curl -L https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/releases/latest/download/aws-sam-cli-linux-x86_64.zip -o aws-sam-cli-linux-x86_64.zip
      - run: unzip aws-sam-cli-linux-x86_64.zip -d sam-installation
      - run: sudo ./sam-installation/install
      - run:
          name: AWS authentication
          command: |
            read -r AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY AWS_SESSION_TOKEN \<<< \
              $(aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity \
              --role-arn ${AWS_ROLE_ARN} \
              --role-session-name "CircleCI-${CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_ID}-${CIRCLE_JOB}" \
              --web-identity-token $CIRCLE_OIDC_TOKEN \
              --duration-seconds 3600 \
              --query 'Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]' \
              --output text)
              echo export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" >> $BASH_ENV
              echo export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" >> $BASH_ENV
              echo export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="$AWS_SESSION_TOKEN" >> $BASH_ENV
      - run: npm run CICDPackage
      - run: npm run CICDDeploy

workflows:
  staging_workflow:
    when:
      and:
        - or:
            - matches:
                pattern: "^master$"
                value: << pipeline.git.branch >>
        - not:
            matches:
              pattern: "^R.+$"
              value: << pipeline.git.tag >>
    jobs:
      - test_and_lint
      - deploy_staging:
          context: aws-staging
          requires:
            - test_and_lint

  prod_workflow:
    when:
      and:
        - or:
            - matches:
                pattern: "^master$"
                value: << pipeline.git.branch >>
        - or:
            - matches:
                pattern: "^R.+$"
                value: << pipeline.git.tag >>
    jobs:
      - test_and_lint
      - deploy_prod:
          context: aws-prod
          requires:
            - test_and_lint
```

Note it also exports the temp AWS credentials to >> $BASH_ENV so they are available in other steps